# onbeforeunload while page loads

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, onbeforeunload

I'm just curious if things like this is possible >> While still loading a web page, is it possible to return an onbeforeunload like dialog when a user try to navigate to other page or close the browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i made this to display a message to be display before someone quits my site, and this gives them the option to stay or leave the page.

I used jquery so you have to add the link to jquery to your site, yo can do this calling a script tag with the src pointing to the next url:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

and after that just add the next code on your webpage

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{  
   var flag  = true;  
   function Close()
   {  
      if(flag)
      {
         return "Are you sure you want to leave?";}
      }
   }  
   window.onbeforeunload = Close;  
});
```

This will call the Close function at the onbeforeunload event, and will ask if you want to leave or stay

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Your codes works fine. But I think I posted a wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is I have this set of code that exports a PDF file, I used TCPDF on this one.

```
$('#export').click(function() {
        var conf = confirm("This will generate a PDF file of all the list of products. Continue ?");

        if (conf)
        {
            $('#ajaxloader').css('visibility', 'visible');
            var href = "http://"+url+"/export/items.php";
            window.open(href, '_self');
        }
    });
```

When I click the button, it downloads the pdf file that contains a list of products, but my problem it's taking about more than 30 seconds to render, I already set the time limit so I'll no problem with that, what I want to do is to display a loader while rendering the pdf file, then hide it afterwards.